# Chinese site: Google Analytics "Tracking Not Installed" issue

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, universal-analytics

We have Chinese site "site.cn" which is hosted in Hong Kong and have Chinese cCTLD domain .cn.

There is Universal Analytics tracking code installed. It is installed correctly, but there is the status in admin area "Tracking Not Installed" and no data is flowing.

Have used GA Debug plugin for Chrome to see the data sending to Google and it looks like all is OK - http://joxi.ru/Y2LyDxXSBjVDA6

Read a lot of info on the Internet like "this option is buggy", "the status may not show it correctly" but there are almost two months have passed and still NO data is flowing.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange thing, but after one of ordinary releases it began to work and it looks like everything is ok now.